# Laravel hasMany relationship, limit with query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Scenario:**
On a `hasMany` relationship, using the `with` function (for eager loading), I want to limit the results from each of the rows within (instead of the total).

I am following this tutorial (as I think it's the only way to achieve what I need from what I've read on SO) - https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

I have a `Model` - Room that `hasMany` Reviews.

**Room Model:**

```
class Room extends Scopes\BaseModel

   public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }

    public function latestReviews()
    {
        return $this->reviews()->latest()->nPerGroup('room_id', 1);
    }
```

**Scopes/BaseModel.php:**

Direct copy from the website's tutorial, but with the namespace of `namespace App\Scopes;`

**Controller using the with function:**

```
class Room extends Scopes\BaseModel

$rooms = Room::where('room_types_id', $specialism_id)
            ->with('latestReviews')
            ->get();
```

**Error:**

> RelationNotFoundException in RelationNotFoundException.php line 20:
>   Call to undefined relationship [latestReviews] on model [App\Room].

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this. the first one is more like:

```
Room::with(['reviews' => function ($q) {
                $q->where('*CONDITION IF NEEDED*')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1);
            }])->where('room_types_id', $specialism_id)->get();
```

The second way is using accessors.

```
public function getLatestReviewAttribute(){
    return Review::where('room_id', $this->attributes['id'])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(1)->get();
}
```

and you can access it on your view by using `$room->latest_review->review_column_name;` 
While on your controller you can just do `Room::all();`;

Comment: Thank you but the two solutions limit the total number of reviews, not the total number of reviews for each room.

Comment: The second one limits the number of the reviews for each room in the collection

Comment: Where do I use the accessor method please?

Comment: In the rooms model